# What is the default logical operator for multiple filters in Cloud Custodian Policies?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudcustodian

Looking at the following Cloud Custodian policy:

```
policies:
  - name: ec2-ssm-check
    resource: ec2
    filters:
      - type: ssm
        key: PingStatus
        value: Online
      - type: ssm
        key: PlatformName
        value: Ubuntu
      - type: ssm
        key: PlatformVersion
        value: 18.04
```

There are three filteres used together. How are they evaluated? do all of them need to match or just one would be enough?

I read the documentations [here](https://cloudcustodian.io/docs/filters.html) but nothing is mentioned about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can check here.** https://cloudcustodian.io/docs/quickstart/tagCompliance.html

In short- It will start evaluating the first filter to last and if all the filters match, then the policy will execute.

If any of the filters fail, then it will skip. If you want to execute if any of the filter matches, then use OR for the documentation you linked https://cloudcustodian.io/docs/filters.html